# Slow rendering with table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I´m having a speed issue to load 3370 results in a table, it takes 13 seconds.  I´m using jquery.tablesorter-2.22.5.js with the filter and pager widget activated.  Also I use jquery-2.1.4.  I need to have the filter widget activated in order to filter the results.  I would like considering changing the library as the last option.

Any ideas or solution is appreciated.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the only really well scaling solution for that large tables is to use Ajax queries with the pager function of tablesorter.

That being said I'd also try to use the latest version of Mottie's tablesorter ( 2.28.5 ) as well as the latest JQuery - version since there might be some performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a trick when first building the table/initializing the tablesorter that works pretty well. I was able to reduce the time to initialize one of my largest tables from 20ish seconds down to about 4.

Basically what i did was built the table, thead, and tbody all separate from each other.  I only initialized the table, the thead(and its contents) and just the  tag through the function that builds the tablesorter - it basically initializes immediately.  From there, put your tbody text into the tbody of the table and then run a .update() function to your table.

It's a stupid little trick, but it definitely works

Comment: This trick worked for me as well. Good idea! The only problem is when I want to use it in combination with context menu.